# Как прописать значение из LocalStorage в код скрипта на странице?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-api

коллеги. Нужна помощь с забором данных из локарсторгаш.)
САБЖ:
Имеется лендос. На него приходит ссылка с параметром - ID Пикселя ФайсБука. Этот параметр сохранятеся в LocalStorage.
Юзер делает заказ. Переходит на страницу спасибо.
Там стоит код, в который надо ВЕРНУТЬ в явном виде значение из Стораджа.
Под явно я имею ввиду непосредственно поставить это значение в код пиксела
Крыввой набросок, который скорее покажет идею -
[Кодепен с наброском](https://codepen.io/emelyanova/pen/LYVWwMR)

```
<div class="pxl" style="display: none;"></div>

    var px = localStorage.getItem('px');
    var box = document.querySelector('.pxl');
    box.innerHTML = px;
    var pxPrint = box.innerHTML;
    !function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
        if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
            n.callMethod ?
                n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
        };
        if (!f.fbq) f.fbq = n; n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0';
        n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
        t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
    }(window, document, 'script',
        'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', 'pxPrint');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
    fbq('track', 'Lead')

<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
        src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=pxPrint&ev=PageView&noscript=1" /></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Как тут поступить?

PS
Я уж думала сначала, в какой див значение упихать

Но вот Явно прописать не получиться.

Чтобы при инспекции кода он был как бы innerHTML.

Comment: что значит в явном виде? ну вычитайте значение, и вставьте куда вам нужно...

Comment: Под явно я имею ввиду непосредственно поставить это значение в код пиксела. Чтобы при инспекции кода он был как бы innerHTML

Comment: `document.getElementbyId('px1').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('px');` Или что надо?

Comment: если вы хотите чтобы вам ответили, то переформулируйте вопрос (напишите что имеете, и что хотите в итоге), и дайте минимальный воспроизводимый (возможно, не верный) код. Слова такие как САБЖ, ФайсБука лучше написать на Русском (Английском) языках. Ну и просто от меня...после того как вернете значение с `localStorage`, как оно должно выглядеть, куда вставиться, и какие операции с ним будут производиться. Напишите конкретно чем вам не нравится метод, который предложил пользователь @Polina ?

Answer (score 0):

Коллеги, пришлось дописать Костыль: приклеить к ссылке доп параметр в виде Пикселя НАСИЛЬНО, т.к. исходно это не делалось. Затем уже забирать из ссылки.

Т.е. получается так:
Помещаем в LstG
Забираем из LstG формируем ссылку с этим параметром и его значением.
На странице спасибо забираем уже из ссылки.

Прочие методы просто не отсылали событие в ФБук.

Comment: не понятна как задача, так и способ решения (как на меня вообще странный)....